# Why doesn't GitHub preserve line breaks in AsciiDoc?

Tags: github, asciidoc

I've stumbled upon an issue where GitHub refuses to preserve the line breaks in code blocks within AsciiDoc readme files or wiki pages. Googling the problem produced [a bug on the GitHub tracker](https://github.com/dagwieers/asciidoc-odf/issues/2), which marks the issue as resolved without a good explanation.

What should I do to make GitHub preserve line breaks?

Comment: I suggest to ask directly at the mentioned issue as the devs of AsciiDoc rather read their own issue tracker than stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub is no longer using Asciidoc ([Announcement](http://asciidoctor.org/news/asciidoctor-announcement.html)), they are using [Asciidoctor](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor) instead.
The link I provided highlights the differences between Asciidoc and Asciidoctor and might be what you need to create your .asciidoc with the above considerations.